# Как центрировать объект в Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Да-да, но у меня нужно, что бы этот объект был прямо в центре. (чтобы это работало не только на чекбоксе).

```
def clsi1():
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open('https://www.fadcomp.tk', new=0)

def github():
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open('https://github.com/Fander-Company/urlshortener', new=0)

def projectsite():
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open('https://briefa.ga', new=0)

def chkstatebind():
    chk_state.set(True)

def callback(*args):
    print(f"the variable has changed to '{var.get()}'")

root = Tk()
root.title("BriefaGa")
chk_state = StringVar()
chk_state.set(False)  # задайте проверку состояния чекбокса
chk = Checkbutton(root, text='Custom', var=chk_state)
#chk.pack(fill='both', expand=5)
chk.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
txt = Entry()
var = tkinter.StringVar(value="one")
var.trace("w", callback)
#chk.bind('<Double-Button-1>', chk.focus())
#chk.bind('<Button-1>', chkstatebind())
root["bg"] = "white"
menu = Menu(root)
new_item1 = Menu(menu)
new_item2 = Menu(menu)
new_item3 = Menu(menu)
new_item1.add_command(label='Site', command=clsi1)
new_item1.add_command(label='GitHub Project', command=github)
new_item1.add_command(label='Project Site', command=projectsite)
menu.add_cascade(label='Information', menu=new_item1)
root.config(menu=menu)

panelFrame2 = Frame(root, height=30, bg='gray')
textFrame = Frame(root, height=340, width=600)

panelFrame2.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
textFrame.pack(side='bottom', fill='both', expand=1)


lbl1 = Label(panelFrame2, text='Alpha Version 1.0.0 - en')
lbl1.pack(side='right')
lbl1['bg'] = "gray"
lbl1['fg'] = "white"

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @СергейКох не сработало. сдвинулось, но не центр.

Comment: @СергейКох я знаю, он у меня добавлен.

Comment: @СергейКох просто я показал не весь код.

Comment: Тогда почитай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example и попробуй метод place().

Comment: Есть еще в этом методе relx, rely.

Comment: @СергейКох у меня просто пропадает checkbox после этих параметров, т.е. пустое окно.

Comment: Тогда все таки размести минимально воспроизводимый пример, чтоб его можно скопировать и воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: @СергейКох https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/996131130212352075/998990581017612298/unknown.png после anchor или relx rely

Comment: @СергейКох дополнил место с chk.place() в коде. Посмотрите

Comment: @СергейКох вновь дополнил во избежании новых ошибок и недочетов.

Comment: У вас по центру располагается текстовое поле, при методе pack оно не дает чекбоксу заехать на него, а при методе place оно накладывается скрывая его. Вы можете его увидеть задав цвет textFrame = Frame(root, height=340, width=600, bg='green').